# How to disable multiple elements triggering?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The document contain 2 elements with the same class, one is rendered from the page's initial load and the other one added later with an ajax call.

in my js code I'm doing:

```
 $(document).on('click', '.some-class', function(e) {
     some code
 });
```

The problem is that both of the elements are getting this "click" event

I've tried to add `e.target == this` check inside the handler but it didn't work.

Comment: Which element do you want to get clicked only??

Comment: Can you post some html code?

Answer (score 1):

If I guess correctly, you want to avoid event propagation. Try:

```
$(document).on('click', '.some-class', function(e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
    //Your code
 });
```

Comment: He/she should use event.stopImmediatePropagation() instead of stopPropogation because it keeps the rest of the handlers from being executed and prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree.

Comment: @Manish Jangir Blogaddition.com: `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` is also an option. I'm not sure if this is what he/she wants

Answer (score 0):

If you want only first element to get clicked then use the following code

```
$('.some-class').on('click', function(e) {some code});
```

Because this code will not work for the elements that are inserted dynamically in the DOM.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution that will work for both cases

Comment: But you have an objection if both are clicked as you said in your question

Comment: What is your exact problem. Could you elaborate it once?

Comment: You can add some extra class as Damien Black said in previous answer and then check in your function by if($(this).hasClass('extra')) and try.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to find a way to distinguish between the two elements.

The easiest way to differentiate the two, if possible, would be to have the ajax call add the element with an extra class, like .extra. then you could use $(document).on('click', '.some-class.extra', function(e) {some code});

If you can't add the extra class in the ajax then you have to find a more creative way to distinguish the two. For example, if one of the elements is in a descendant of a div with the class .parent, use $(document).on('click', '.parent .some-class', function(e) {some code});

You might have to get very tricky if there isn't an easy way to distinguish them by layout. For example, if the element you are interested in is the second one in a div, and the other one is the first one you could use $(document).on('click', '.some-class:nth-child(2)', function(e) {some code});

Look into "[Css Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)" to figure the ways you can select the elements you want.